# Is there a way to read in buttons in excel using python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, button

I want to read in this excel sheet but it is having buttons in it (not the cells with dropdown list). Whenever, I try to read this sheet using pandas or openpyxl it gives 'Nan' values to those cells where buttons are present because there are no values inside those cells only buttons are present on the top of those cells. So, I am unable to read in those buttons. Could anyone please help me with this? [excel sheet pic which I am trying to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p7g4.png)

```
df = pd.read_excel('test_sheet.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Table 2', skiprows=86, usecols='B:AM') 
print(df[:2])
```

Comment: Could you share the excel file and post your code so that I can know what is wrong

Comment: Sorry, not able to share the file. But have uploaded the block of code. Could you please have a look at it once?